# Is NSOutputStream thread safe for the close and writeData methods?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, network-programming

My program frequently crashes (bad access) on the following line:

```
int writeSize = [_outputStream write:pCopyOfDataBuff maxLength:sendLength];
```

pCopyOfDataBuff is a

```
pCopyOfDataBuff = new unsigned char [sendLength];
```

allocated and filled with data on the stack just before the crashing line. Context is a special thread handling this stream.

When I stop in the debugger, using symbolic exception breakpoint, I find that the _outputStream was actually **closed**.

```
[_outputStream close];
```

was closed in the MAIN thread. Now this may have happened concurrently.

My question: Is it at all safe to handle an NSOutputStream like this, in multiple threads? Should I synchronize ALL calls to an NSStream to the same thread?

Thanks. I can't find simple answer in the docs.

Comment: To my knowledge, it is safe to access a stream from different threads. You should setup a quick test in order to figure whether this is the cause of the crash: have two dispatch queues, create a paired stream (via CFStreamCreateBoundPair), open the two streams, then write in queue A and read from queue B. close the stream from a third queue at random times.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a little too much work to set up all this for testing, while different streams may behave differently (your suggested test is generic - no networking involved).

Comment: I should add that, if you schedule the stream on a run loop, you must ensure that you access the stream only from that thread's run loop. I apologize, that I didn't asked how you use that stream beforehand.

Comment: So I must synchronize all my messages to the stream on the same thread (and runloop) I created for it. So what did you mean by "it is safe to access a stream from different threads" ?

Answer (score 3):

Recently encountered the same problem. I discovered that some delegate on the main thread shuts down the operation queue with [[myQueue cancelAllOperations]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/cancelAllOperations) and closes the connection as followed:

```
-(void)closeStream:(NSStream *)stream {
    [stream setDelegate:nil];
    [stream close];
    [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

My explanation was that in the middle of writing with `[self.outputStream write:bytes maxLength:bytesRecieved];` the output stream was closed.

I resolved it by waiting on the NSOperationQueue to finish: [[myQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished).

Hopes this helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: can you explain why this is "same problem" ? My stream runs on its own thread's runloop, while yours seems to be running on the Main thread. Also, I don't have any operation queue involved --- can you elaborate on the relevance of your myQueue? what stream related operations are added to this operation queue?